# Glitch filter implementation

Tags: filter

I am trying to implement the LTC4361 chip using opAMPS on a bread board. There is a statement which reads - "V trip threshold and
a 10µs glitch filter" (page 6 of datasheet).
[image: Glitch filter]

How can I implement a glitch filter ?
If I understand right, a glitch filter is something that filters out small ripples. The 10uSec means any ripple <= 10uS is filtered. Can I not do it using a ceramic cap and with the 1/2.pi.f.c formula, find out the waveform or filter properties ?

I intend to do that in spice. Is my approach right ?

Comment: Why would LTC or any chip supplier giveaway all the family silver?

Comment: Like that would stop others from doing such a thing !!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually a glitch filter is just an OR gate on which one of the inputs is a delayed version of the original signal, as show in the schematic below.

[image]

That is for a (reset) glitch filter in the digital world. I'm not sure if there's more to it in that MOSFET driver.

Comment: How can I implement that in analogue ?

Comment: Various implementations are discussed in [this patent application US 20140055165A1](http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US20140055165.pdf).